# How to set the radius of the four corners of the echarts background?

Tags: javascript, echarts

I have been learning how to use ECharts recently.
I want to change the radius of the four corners of the echarts background, like this:

[image]

**Operating environment:**
echarts: 5.4.2
vue3

I tried using three methods.
**1. Added option attribute: borderRadius: [20, 20, 20, 20], (this is the answer from chatgpt)**

```js
option = {
  backgroundColor :'#999',
  **borderRadius: [20, 20, 20, 20],**
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [120, 200, 150, 80, 70, 110, 130],
      type: 'bar'
    }
  ]
};
```

**2. Set the radian of the echarts container itself.**

```html
<div ref="EnergyCalendar" style="border-radius: 20px;height: 320px; width: 100%;">
</div>
```

**3. Wrap the div outside the echarts container and set the radius of the div.**

```html
<div style="border-radius: 20px;">
  <div ref="EnergyCalendar" style="height: 320px; width: 100%;">
  </div>
</div>
```

But none of these three methods are effective.

Can someone familiar with ECharts help explain how to implement this feature?
Thank you in advance for your answer!

Comment: Radians are a measurement of arc displacement (e.g. π radians = 180°). Radius is a measure from the centre of an arc to the edge (e.g. `border-radius: 20px`). I think the subject of the OP should state radius, not radians.

Comment: I edited the post changing "radians" to "radius", it's obvious that the OP is interested in setting the border radius of the chart, and with that the question has merit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `canvas` renderer, you may style the canvas element inside the container:

```css
#chart-container canvas{
  border-radius: 20px
}
```

If you're using the `svg` renderer you may style the svg element inside the container:

```css
#chart-container svg{
  border-radius: 20px
}
```

Of course, you may combine these, to cover both cases.

- an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/hj9rs0nb/1/) with canvas
- an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/hj9rs0nb/) with svg